# ios pause audio when page was changed

Tags: ios, ipad, caching, audio, html5-audio

The problem shows on IPad with IOS 8.0.1.
It is infinite audio, that playing on page1.html
I supposed that the sound will stop playing if I go to another page (for example page2.html), but it still have been playing.
I tried to use unload, pagehide and visibilitychange events to stop it, but all my efforts failed.

The code

```
<audio id="sound" loop src="audio/baby.mp3"></audio>
<script>        
        var player = document.getElementById("sound");
        window.addEventListener("unload", function () {
            player.pause();
        });
        if ('onpagehide' in window)
            window.addEventListener("pagehide", function () {
            player.pause();
        });    
        if ('onvisibilitychange' in window)
            window.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function () {
            player.pause();
        });
</script>
```

The sound stops only if I reload the page, where it was activated.

Comment: Find the topic adout crossbrowser using of page visibility API, but the event 'visibilitychange' not fires at all on tab change, minimize browser or going other url.

Answer (score 0):

Find out!

Maybe it's bug of Safari:
Using native attribute "loop" you cannot stop audio.

So I replaced it with my own loop function, that includes page visibility check

```
player.addEventListener("ended", function() {
                    if (windowVisible)
                        player.play();
                });
```